# R: download data securely using TLS/SSL

Tags: r, ssl, curl, ssl-certificate, rcurl

### Official Statements

In the past the base R `download.file()` was unable to work with HTTPS protocols and it was necessary to use RCurl. Since [R 3.3.0](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2016-1/r-changes.pdf):

> All builds have support for https: URLs in the default methods for download.file(), url() and code making use of them. Unfortunately that cannot guarantee that any particular https: URL can be accessed. ...  Different access methods may allow different protocols or use private certificate bundles ...

The `download.file()`  help still says:

> Contributed package 'RCurl' provides more comprehensive facilities  to download from URLs.

which (by the way includes cookies and headers management).

Based on [RCurl FAQ](http://www.omegahat.net/RCurl/FAQ.html) (look for "When I try to interact with a URL via https, I get an error"),  HTTPS URLs can be managed with:

```
getURL(url, cainfo="CA bundle")
```

where `CA bundle` is the path to a certificate authority bundle file. One such a bundle is available from the curl site itself:
https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

### Current status

*Tests are based on Windows platforms*

For many HTTPS websites  `download.file()` works as stated:

```
download.file(url="https://www.google.com", destfile="google.html")
download.file(url="https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile="cacert.pem")
```

As regards RCurl, using the `cacert.pem` bundle, downloaded above, one might get an error:

```
library(RCurl)
getURL("https://www.google.com", cainfo = "cacert.pem")    
# Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
#   SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

In this instance, simply removing the reference to the certificate bundle solves the problem:

```
getURL("https://www.google.com")                      # works
getURL("https://www.google.com", ssl.verifypeer=TRUE) # works
```

`ssl.verifypeer = TRUE` is used to be sure that success is not due to `getURL()` suppressing  security. The argument is documented in [RCurl FAQ](http://www.omegahat.net/RCurl/FAQ.html).

However, in other instances, the connection fails:

```
getURL("https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem")
# Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
#  error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

And similarly, using the previously downloaded bundle:

```
getURL("https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", cainfo = "cacert.pem")
# Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
#   error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

The same error happens even when suppressing the security:

```
getURL("https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", ssl.verifypeer=FALSE)
# same error as above
```

### Questions

1. How to use HTTPS properly in RCurl?
2. As regards mere file downloads (no headers, cookies, etc.), is there any benefit in using RCurl instead of `download.file()`?
3. Is RCurl become obsolete and should we opt for [curl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/index.html)?

### Update

The issue persists as of 
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30) under Windows 10.

Comment: Winston Chang (writer of R Graphics Cookbook) has a repository called [downloader](https://github.com/wch/downloader) for downloading files with HTTPS that has no external dependencies which is advertised as an alternative to RCurl.

Comment: @ctesta01: Actually none of the RCurl features is found in `downloader`. In fact, the latter is just a "a wrapper for the `download.file` function". Note also that the package is rather old: in the past perhaps, a wrapper could help to abstract platform specific download issues, but currently  `download.file` is optimised for the platform, so there is no practical point in using downloader.

Comment: @antonio are these sporadic failures or do they fail consistently for you?  I've tried each of the above scenarios several times, on R 3.3.3 (MacOS) and R 3.3.2 (Linux), both with RCurl 1.95-4.8, and I have yet to see a failure.

Comment: @anthonyserious: Thanks for feedback. Please, see update section.

Answer (score 2):

openssl bundled with RCurl  is a bit old currently, which does not support the TLS v1.2

Yes, [curl](https://github.com/jeroen/curl#readme) package is OK

Or you can use [httr](https://github.com/r-lib/httr) package which is a wrapper for the [curl](https://github.com/jeroen/curl#readme) package

```
> library("httr")
> GET("https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem",config(sslversion=6,ssl_verifypeer=1))
Response [https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem]
  Date: 2017-08-16 17:07
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: application/x-pem-file
  Size: 256 kB
<BINARY BODY>
```

Comment: As a package RCurl is _relatively_ [recent (2016-03-01)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html). Should the bundled openssl  be older than this, this is like to say that RCurl is unmantained and should not be on CRAN.